# Is there user Search Functionality in Firebase?

Tags: php, html, search, firebase

I am wondering if there is search function capabilities in Firebase so that if the user enters a search they can pull information from the tables?

Comment: Are you asking if you can query from a Firebase database? Because querying is a basic functionality of all databases. https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html

Comment: @Jamil im looking to be able to allow the user to search say a table name and retrieve the information nested in it outputted onto the page

Comment: You should update your question to ask that. It's very vague as it is. Do you know how to connect to a database in PHP? Do you know how to query a database? If not, I would start with some tutorials on PHP and Firebase integration to get yourself off the ground. If yes, let's see what code you have so far, so we can help.